# How come I can't access Youtube videos on Chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, flash-player

When I try to watch Youtube videos in Google Chrome on Ubuntu Quantal Quetzal, I get the following "Couldn't load plugin." message.

[image]

I tried to go to "Wrench" -> Tools -> Task Manager in Google Chrome, close the Shockwave process, and reload the page with the Youtube video, but the problem persists.

Am I missing a plugin? What is erring?

=====

**Update**:

Thanks everyone! You're awesome.

After a while I finally solved the problem. After going to `chrome://plugins`, I found that I had a mysterious plugin called `libpepflashplayer`. I disabled it, and now, I can play Youtube videos. Here's how my `chrome://plugins` settings look like now.

[image]

However, is this a good way to solve the problem? Is there a deeper problem I may be having? Like my Chrome browser not updating correctly?

Comment: Is Chrome getting updated correctly? `chrome://chrome` should show version 24.0.1312.57.

Comment: I have 24.0.1312.56, but that's not far behind...

Comment: Adobe Flash Player is directly integrated into Chrome as  [libpepflashplayer.so](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108086). Probably since you had Adobe's Flash plugin installed as well, the two were conflicting. Disabling one fixed the issue. Also, if you found a solution, you should post it as an answer instead of editing it into your question.

Comment: Thanks! I pursued another solution from an answer below since I think getting rid of Pepper Flash entirely is a better solution.

Comment: @DavidFaux: Please don't add your solution to your question. Please make it an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a different version but maybe this helps you anyways.

I had this problem with the latest dev channel. `Version 26.0.1397.2 dev`

I fixed it by deleting the folder `PepperFlash` in `.config/google-chrome/` and `.config/google-chrome/Default/Pepper\ Data/`, for some reason there is a copy of of the .so file for the pepper flash plugin, which is not really needed because there original copy on `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/` should be loaded as well which may be causing a conflict or something.

Make sure to backup your whole `.config/google-chrome/` folder just in case.

I don't use the standalone flash package anymore, just the pepper flash version included with Chrome, just in case you are wondering.

Comment: You inspired me to check something ... see my update.

Comment: Your answer worked too! As you noted, I just got rid of PepperFlash entirely as opposed to just disabling it.

Comment: As the Adobe says, the correct version of flashplayer for Linux is the 11.2 instead the last 11.5.
If you go here http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?no_redirect you can read:


`NOTE: Adobe Flash Player 11.2 will be the last version to target Linux as a supported platform. Adobe will continue to provide security backports to Flash Player 11.2 for Linux.`

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem yesterday, so upgraded by downloading and re-installing chrome (it is now Version 24.0.1312.57 and still doesn't work.

So I went back to using Chromium and Chromium works Version 23.0.1271.97 Ubuntu 10.04 (23.0.1271.97-0ubuntu0.10.04.1)

As you can see am on Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Adobe Flash player.

Comment: Adobe Flash Player comes pre-installed with Chrome.

Comment: I believe that is still in beta and you have to enable it.

Comment: Nope, flash runs fine in my Ubuntu 12.10 Chrome install without any extra installation.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to reinstall the Adobe flash plugin even if you already have it installed. Then go to `chrome://plugins/` to make sure that it is enabled in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I had an issue after updating ubuntu on an older pc. I didn't see a pepper file or anything that some other people had issues with. I went to the ubuntu software center, found flash under the installed tab, and uninstalled it. I think this left the old Flash 10 on the pc. It is now working as it did before the update and flash is no longer crashing.

Comment: Why would some down vote this? What is the reasoning?